# How to disable track changes and enable tracking in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How to disable track changes and enable tracking in ckeditor [image]

As you can see in the image that tracking is enabled and track changes is disabled.
i need this condition but am not getting it.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image that you're showing, you want to:

- Enable change tracking
- Hide visibility of tracked changes (i.e., show changes === false)

Create a reference to the track changes plugin, then call the plugin's `toggleShow()` function with the value *false*:

```
const editorInstance = CKEDITOR.instances['editor-1']; // Where 'editor-1' is the name of your editor's instance
const liteRef = editorInstance.plugins.lite.findPlugin(editorInstance);
liteRef.toggleShow(false);
```

Notes:

- *Enabling* the show/hide button is different from setting change visibility. E.g.:

  - [Show/Hide Changes button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C862Z.png)
- Whenever you *enable* the change tracking feature and turn tracking on, the show/hide button is *enabled* and the visibility of changes is set to true.